# The captions of my graph are overlapping. How can I fix this?

Tags: r, axis-labels, mosaic-plot

So I was plotting this code, but the text is overlapping. How can I fix this?
[image]

```
mayors <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/brmayors.csv")
head(mayors)

mosaicplot(table(mayors$SIGLA_PARTIDO, mayors$DESCRICAO_SEXO), main = "Gender by party", color = "turquoise")

mosaicplot(table(mayors$SIGLA_PARTIDO, mayors$DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO), main = "Level of education by party", color = "plum")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the direction of the axis labels with `las =`. You can also control the size of the text with `cex.axis =`.

```
mosaicplot(table(mayors$SIGLA_PARTIDO, mayors$DESCRICAO_GRAU_INSTRUCAO),
           main = "Level of education by party",
           color = "plum",
           las = 2,
           cex.axis = 0.5)
```

[image]